# Unable to cast a shadow with THREE.js and Mapbox GL

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add a THREE.js scene into a Mapbox GL visualization following [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/). I've added a sphere and a ground plane and a DirectionalLight. Now I'm trying to get the light to cast a shadow on the ground plane. Adding a `DirectionalLightHelper` and a `CameraHelper` for the light's shadow camera, everything looks pretty reasonable to me:

[image: A DirectionLight not casting a shadow]

I'd expect to see a shadow for the sphere on the plane.

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/danvk/a1864cf1422ebc7958c8c76a2395db37#file-statue-mapbox-js), but here are the highlights:

```js
class SpriteCustomLayer {
  type = 'custom';
  renderingMode = '3d';

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.gui = new dat.GUI();
    THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp.set(0, 0, 1);
  }

  async onAdd(map, gl) {
    this.camera = new THREE.Camera();

    const centerLngLat = map.getCenter();
    this.center = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(centerLngLat, 0);
    const {x, y, z} = this.center;
    this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .makeTranslation(x, y, z)
      .scale(new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 1));

    this.map = map;
    this.scene = this.makeScene();

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: map.getCanvas(),
      context: gl,
      antialias: true,
    });
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    this.renderer.autoClear = false;
  }

  makeScene() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25));

    const s = this.center.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(0.000002360847837325531, 0.000004566603480958114, 0.00000725142167844218);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;

    light.shadow.camera.left = -0.000002383416166278454 * 2;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 0.000002383416166278454 * 2;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -0.000002383416166278454 * 2;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 0.000002383416166278454 * 2;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.0000012388642793465356;
    light.shadow.camera.far *= s;

    scene.add(light);
    this.light = light;

    {
      const planeSize = 500;
      const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      const texture = loader.load('/checker.png');
      texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      const repeats = 10;
      texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

      const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
      const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: texture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      });

      const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
      plane.scale.setScalar(s);
      plane.receiveShadow = true;
      scene.add(plane);
    }

    {
      const sphereRadius = 5e-7;
      const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(sphereRadius, 32, 32);
      const sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#CA8'});
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);

      mesh.position.set(0, 0, 5e-6);
      mesh.castShadow = true;
      mesh.receiveShadow = false;
      sphereMat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
      scene.add(mesh);
    }

    return scene;
  }

  render(gl, matrix) {
    this.camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .fromArray(matrix)
      .multiply(this.cameraTransform);
    this.renderer.state.reset();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.map.triggerRepaint();
  }
}
```

Mapbox GL JS uses a coordinate system where the entire world is in [0, 1] so the coordinates are pretty tiny. It also uses x/y for lat/lng and z for up, which is different than usual Three.js coordinates.

How can I get the shadow to appear? I'm using Three.js r109 and Mapbox GL JS 1.4.0. I've tried replacing the `PlaneBufferGeometry` with a thin `BoxGeometry` to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried disabling `side: THREE.DoubleSide` in `planeMat`? I've always had problems with shadows being cast onto double-sided meshes.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. I tried replacing `planeMat` with a thin `BoxGeometry` and that didn't help, either, so I'd be surprised if it was something to do with sides.

Comment: Hmm, well your code looks fine at first glance. What's the resulting value of `light.shadow.camera.far` when you multiply it by `s`? Is it bigger than `.camera.near`? Also, is there any chance you can make this into a live example? It could a problem in the MapboxGL layer, but it's hard to tell exactly with only a fraction of the code.

Comment: I provided a link to the full code but you'll need to get a Mapbox token to run it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not gonna do any of that.

Comment: Just something to think about: Based purely on my observations, JavaScript tends to get weird when performing operations on numbers with decimal values less than `1e-6`. Your values are danger-close to that range. I recommend increasing the scale of whatever it is you're doing just to see if the shadow appears when using larger values.

Comment: @TheJim01 JavaScript uses IEEE 64-bit floating points, which have [15-17 decimal digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). That's several orders of magnitude more than should be necessary here. But it's not impossible that THREE.js has some issues with this behind the scenes.

Comment: JavaScript may use 64-bit floats, but [WebGL (1.0) only supports up to 32-bit floats (`GLfloat`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Types), which cuts your potential precision to 7 decimal places (you can assume JavaScript is making the conversion nicely, rather than just dumping the bits in place). With that in mind, I created a minimal scene using values in your scale range (generally less than `1e-5`). When I rendered, I saw no shadow. I then "scaled-up" the values into integer-range values, and got a shadow from the render.

Comment: Good point @TheJim01. I put the Meshes and Lights in a `THREE.Group` with integer coordinates and applied the scale to that (`group.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(s, s, s));`). Still not seeing the shadow, unfortunately, but I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: @danvk Did you get anywhere with this? I'm currently experiencing a similar issue and curious if you managed to solve it.

Comment: No, I never solved the issue. I think @TheJim01 is onto something with the small scale, but I haven’t been able to piece together a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Forget everything I said in my old answer.

The example below scales things *WAY* down and the shadow remains.

The kicker was here:

```js
shadowLight.shadow.camera.near *= (scaleDown) ? 0.1 : 10;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.far *= (scaleDown) ? 0.1 : 10;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // <========= !!!!!
```

I was updating the scale, but wasn't updating the `near`/`far` of the shadow camera. Then, once I was, I was forgetting to update that camera's projection matrix. With all the pieces back together, it seems to be working well.

Try adding a call to update the shadow-casting light's camera's projection matrix after you configure the values.

If it still doesn't work, maybe you can use my example to figure out what's going on in your code.

If *MY* example doesn't work for you, then it might be your hardware doesn't support the level of precision you need.

```js
// just some random colors to show it's actually rendering
const colors = [
  0xff0000, // 1e+1
  0x00ff00, // 1e+0
  0x0000ff, // 1e-1
  0xffff00, // 1e-2
  0xff00ff, // 1e-3
  0x00ffff, // 1e-4
  0xabcdef, // 1e-5
  0xfedcba, // 1e-6
  0x883300, // 1e-7
  0x008833, // 1e-8
  0x330088, // 1e-9
  0x338800 // 1e-10
];
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; // turn on shadow mapping
renderer.setClearColor(0xcccccc);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(25, 10, 15);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const camLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
camera.add(camLight);

const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: "gray"
  })
);
floor.receiveShadow = true;
floor.rotation.set(Math.PI / -2, 0, 0);
floor.position.set(0, -1, 0);

const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(2, 16, 32),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: colors[0]
  })
);
sphere.castShadow = true;
sphere.position.set(0, 1, 0);

const shadowLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
shadowLight.castShadow = true;
shadowLight.position.set(-10, 10, 5);

const group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(floor);
group.add(sphere);
group.add(shadowLight);
group.add(camera);

scene.add(group);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resize() {
  const W = window.innerWidth;
  const H = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(W, H);
  camera.aspect = W / H;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
window.onresize = resize;

resize();
render();
let scaler = 10;
let scaleLevel = 10;
let scaleLevelOutput = document.getElementById("scaleLevel");
let scaleDown = true;
let colorIndex = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  colorIndex += (scaleDown) ? 1 : -1;
  scaleLevel *= (scaleDown) ? 0.1 : 10;
  shadowLight.shadow.camera.near *= (scaleDown) ? 0.1 : 10;
  shadowLight.shadow.camera.far *= (scaleDown) ? 0.1 : 10;
  shadowLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  if (scaleLevel < 1e-9 && scaleDown) {
    scaleDown = false;
  }
  if (scaleLevel >= 10 && !scaleDown) {
    scaleDown = true;
  }

  scaleLevelOutput.innerText = `SCALE LEVEL: ${scaleLevel.toExponential()}`;

  group.scale.set(scaleLevel, scaleLevel, scaleLevel);

  sphere.material.color.setHex(colors[colorIndex]);
  sphere.material.needsUpdate = true;

  render();
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scaleLevel {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="scaleLevel">SCALE LEVEL: 1e+1</div>
```